# Is it good practice to give a value to a variable, then change its value immediately after?

Tags: python

Is it good practice to give a value to a variable, then change its value immediately after, like that for example?

```
def get_user_id_from_username(username):
    user_id = db.execute("SELECT id FROM user WHERE username = ?", (username, ))
    for row in user_id:
        user_id = row[0]
    return user_id
```

Basically, I say that user_id is equal to something that's returned by a SQL query. Then whatever is returned is then passed into user_id. Is that a good thing to do or should I have get_id = sql, and then pass the result into user_id... Or is that completely irrelevant?

By the way, unless I completely missed something, that function always work and the query should never return no row because the username is confirmed to exist with a login function. The idea is that the user logs in and once that's successful, then it does a few things, such as save a timestamp for login history, create a session token, get the user id to search for all the data in the database that use this user_id as a foreign key, etc.

So I really just want you to review that single block of code regardless of its context.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Briefly: no, the loop you've shown is very poor practice. But this question is off-topic because it isn't concrete code. In other words, _review that single block of code regardless of its context_ is not something we support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your piece of code is logically incorrect in the following: your select query will return list of already filtered by username IDs - all ID will be the same. So there is no need to iterate over the list of identical IDs and assign each of them to `user_id`.

The idea to reassign data of different type and origin to the same variable (though this works) is bad since it decreases readability of the code and - worse - confuses your way of thinking when constructing the code.

I'd suggest the following code:

```
import sqlite3

def get_user_id_from_usermane(db: sqlite3.Cursor, username: str) -> str:
    user_id_row = db.execute("SELECT id FROM user WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1", (username, ))
    return user_id_row[0]
```